# Using map() to filter image collection iteratively in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

I have an image collection which I want to filter iteratively using a list of tile id's to get the images corresponding to each tile id.

So, I basically want to find an alternative for this code using a for loop or map() function:

```
var id_tile = ee.List(['17RNJ','17RLH','17RMJ','17RMK']);

var Collection1 = MyImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.equals('MGRS_TILE',id_tile.get(0)));
var Collection2 = MyImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.equals('MGRS_TILE',id_tile.get(1)));
var Collection3 = MyImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.equals('MGRS_TILE',id_tile.get(2)));
var Collection4 = MyImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.equals('MGRS_TILE',id_tile.get(3)));
```

I don't know whether is possible to return a collection of collections using the map() function or I have to do this manually as the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ee.Filter.inList()`:

```
var id_tile = ['17RNJ','17RLH','17RMJ','17RMK'];
var filter = ee.Filter.inList('MGRS_TILE', id_tile);
var Collection = MyImageCollection.filter(filter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not doing what I am expecting. This is like a feature collection containing several image collections. In this case is an image collection per each id_tile element and contained all in a single (feature?) collection, but I think it is not possible in GEE...